# How to append select option to a JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add an input and select form elements to a Jquery function but i do not know how to go about it. At the moment i am able to only add one element. That is either an input or select form element. I want the function to contain fields for both input and select form elements.

Jquery code

```
function collectFormData(fields) {
                var data = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                    var $item = $(fields[i]);
                    data[$item.attr('name')] = $item.val();
                }
                return data;
            }
var $inputs = $form.find('input');
var data = collectFormData($inputs)
```

Tried this but does not work.

```
var $selects = $form.find('select')
var $inputs = $form.find('input').append($selects);
var data = collectFormData($inputs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add id to your form like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
...
</fomr>
```

then you can use this function to get all form inputs:

```
var data = {};
$.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
    data[field.name] = field.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function collectFormData(fields) {
    var data = {};
    fields.each(function(){
        var $item = $(this);
        data[$item.attr('name')] = $item.val();
    });
    return data;
}
```